# How can I force Safari to perform a full page reload, without using the mouse?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-cache

I'm using Safari to preview web pages as I develop them on my local server. **I've got 'Disable Caches' checked in the Develop menu.** And yet Safari is still working from a cached version of a stylesheet that's linked from the HTML file being displayed.

I can sometimes override this by Option-clicking the reload button in the location bar, but I want to refresh the page automatically when I save the CSS file. At the moment I'm doing it using an AppleScript that's bound to the Save action in my text editor. I could see using Keyboard Maestro instead. But I need some consistent way to force Safari to do a full reload from the keyboard.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed. Had this problem once with Adblock... It messed up one page in particular, thought it was a stylesheet problem too, tried everything... but it was Adblock messing with it.

Answer (score 55):

Enable the `Develop` menu from `Safari menu - Preferences - Advanced`.

**On Safari version 11.1 and above :**

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> reloads the page ignoring cache.

**On Safari version 9 and above :**

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> reloads the page ignoring cache.

*Emptying caches seems not to reload the stylesheets everytimes…*

**On Safari below version 9 :**

Empty cache and then reload so full "hot key" would be :

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Then

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the page

Of course probably turning opening and closing a `New Private Window`from the `File` would also work but…

Comment: that didn't work for me on Safari 8

Comment: Safari version 9.1.1 does not reload the page with Cmd-Shift-R. I have "Show Develop in menu bar" enabled.

Comment: cmd+shift+R didn't work for me in 9.1.3 either

Comment: Cmd+Shift+R didn't work in Version 10.0.1 (11602.2.14.0.7).

Comment: Checkout [@sayan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1314295/214024) below for a working shortcut

Comment: Is there not a way to do this with just the mouse? A UX issue.

Answer (score 20):

The shortcut has now changed to <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. (Safari 11.1)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

There is an option in the menubar Develop->Disable Caches. This is true for Safari 5.1. I'm not sure for the rest.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please read the second sentence of my question again.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry :)

Comment: I think the keyboard maestro method be to activate the “disable caches” menu bar item, reload the page, then deactivate it.

Answer (score 2):

Hard refresh was removed as a keyboard shortcut in Safari 5.  The old command for that was <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> May work but I can't test here.

Comment: Yes, that's how to refresh the page, but it doesn't bypass the cache.

Comment: Control-F5 just selects the location bar, like Command-L.

Comment: Then it's been disabled completely.  I found a number of threads complaining about it.  There is an extension that I have NOT tested here: http://twitter.com/siracusa/status/15683201068 that may do what you want.

Comment: No, that extension just creates a button in the toolbar (which I guess some people prefer to the icon in the location bar). I also found a lot of threads complaining about it—i was wondering if someone on here had any special knowledge.

Comment: Sorry! :( <15chars>

Comment: Shift + Click on the refresh button

Answer (score 2):

Turn on `Private mode` and refresh the page. It won't get it from the cache in private mode.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: in the develop menu, select "start debugging javascript" and it must reload the code properly. You can then stop debugging...
I know it's not a clean solution and I'm not sure if it works always or in all versions, but it's working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I stumble upon this question and apparently the current answers do not work.

Issue is currently <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> opens the Responsive design.

However if the inspector is open via <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, then the same shortcut does a clean refresh.

Current Safari Version: 12.1.2

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> focus on the address bar
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> full reload for the current address

It seems to work on Safari 9

Comment: And how does one click without a mouse?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq My bad, edited the question.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Safari's preferences and tick "Show develop menu".
In the develop menu, click disable Caches.

Comment: Please read the second sentence of my question.