# Google search site stucks after ADSL credentials renewal

Tags: macos, safari, google-search

Some times I have to reset my ADSL modem, after that google search won't work, I tried browsing other sites like bing.com and duckduckgo.com without any problem, it just gets stuck when I enter either a keyword search on the address bar or an address with domain google.com

The web browser gets stuck showing a blank page with a progress bar at about 20%, but it's just the web page not the browser, I can open other tab and browse to bing.com for instance, and that page load just fine.

The browser is Safari 9.0 running on OS X El Capitan

Comment: This sounds like your browser is still loading the cached page.  Adjust how Safari will cache a page to avoid this behavior.  You really should determine the reason you have to reset your modem, you shouldn't have to do that, it sounds like you are doing it far to often.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll try [this](http://superuser.com/a/610555/142448) to see what happen, regarding the issue with the modem it's mostly because of a crappy ISP